# READ empty file image in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

which i need to update the profil `user` with or without user's photo profile,  here my code in view

```
<input type="file" name="file_foto" class="form-control">
```

how i can read the file is empty or not, to chose when update data is with image or without image.
and how to make `unlink` image to delete previouse image in Codeigniter. thanks

here is my **Controller**

```
if (empty($_FILES['file_foto']['name'])) {
            $data_profil = array(
                'name'=>$name
                );
        }else{
            $foto_up = $this->do_upload_image('file_foto');
            $data_profil = array(               
                'name'=>$name,
                'foto'=>$foto_up['file_name']
                );

        }
```

Comment: Your question will help analysis by providing your involved controller method code and probably the html for the form.

Comment: sory my problem now solve, i use this code `if (empty($_FILES['file_foto']['name']))`

Comment: That is not how you use codeigniter file upload http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_FILES['file_foto']['name'])){
code to upload image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

oh sory all, my problem now solve, just use this code

```
if (empty($_FILES['file_foto']['name']))
```